# SimpleForm - Hidden field with multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, input, simple-form

How do I use a hidden field with multiple values

I tried this but its not working:

```
= f.association :sites, as: :hidden, input_html: {default: ""}
```

Comment: did you try `f.association :sites, input_html: {default: "", hidden: true}` ?